# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract Insertion fail

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am inserting data in to the database using Zend class Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

However in some cases when I put long text in to text fields the query execution failed. So I changed my code according to an answer in this site. Finally my code looks.

```
$objSQL =  $this->objDB->getAdapter()->getConnection()->query($sql);
$result = $objSQL->execute();
```

This fixed the issue. However with this modification I can't update data in the database. IF I change my code to previous way as bellow, then it starts to update.

```
$objSQL = $this->objDB->getAdapter()->prepare($sql);
$result = $objSQL->execute();
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue?  Thank you.

Comment: Where do you explain what your issue is? Please include specific error messages. Generalized terms/phrases like 'it failed', 'doesn't work', etc help nobody.

Comment: Hi If I get proper error message I could check further. Only thing I got for $objSQL->errorInfo() is empty array. Error code is 00000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the issue by changing the code. I decided to remove custom insert sql statements. And I passed those to the Send_DB_Table as array. It worked.

```
$this->objDB->getAdapter()->insert($tableName, $arrayData);
```

Thanks.